# dynamic database and dict cursor in MySQLConnectionPool

Tags: python, mysql, cursor

I have been trying to use connection pool for mysql in python. While searching for options, I came across `MySQLConnectionPool`. It seems to work decently but I am not able to find how to achieve some of the features of MySQL.

1. How to dynamically select database.
2. How to use dict_cursor. For
   normal MySQL without pool, I use
   `cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor`

If someone knows about how to achieve this, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally am able to achieve this.

1. For dynamic database, I have used `Lock` module in `python`. Because I am using pool for a server, I will get concurrent requests which should not alter the database for the connection pool in its  entirety.
2. For dictionary, while creating cursor I set the value of parameter `dictionary` to `True`.

   ```
   lock.acquire()
   try:
       self._pool.set_config(**conn_config)  //conn_config contains the modified database details
       conn = self._pool.get_connection()
       cursor = conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
   except PoolError:
      //do something
   lock.release()
   ```